# How to get the associated data of `OneToOneField()` in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, one-to-one, associated-object

I'm working in `Django 2.0`

I have a model `Note` to save note and two another models to add color labels to the note.

```
class Note(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True, default='Untitled')
    content = models.TextField(blank=True)

class ColorLabels(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    default = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class NoteLabel(models.Model):
    note = models.OneToOneField(Note, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    color_label = models.OneToOneField(ColorLabels, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

with the object of `Note`

```
note = Note.objects.get(pk=1)
```

**I want to access associated `ColorLabels`'s `title` and `value` fields or the `NoteLabel` object.**

since they are one to one field. I tried doing

```
note.note_label
note.NoteLabel
note.note_label_set
```

But all returns error as

```
AttributeError: 'Note' object has no attribute 'note_label_set'
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unless you define `related_name` in your `OneToOneField`, Django will use lowercased model name to access related object. So, `note.notelabel` should work.

Comment: Thanks. Now how can I filter out `notes` based on `color_label` `title`?

Comment: solved it by running `notelabel__color_label__title__iexact`

Answer (score 1):

You can access a `NoteLabel` object with the `Note` object, then access `ColorLabels`'s `title` and `value` fields with the `NoteLabel` object as shown below:

```py
note = Note.objects.get(pk=1)

note.notelabel.color_label.title # Here
note.notelabel.color_label.value # Here
```